# What's the name of this basic formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology

Is there a name for this formula
$$ x^n -y^n = (x-y) \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^{n-1-k} \cdot y^k$$

Comment: No. It's just a consequence of the fact that $y$ is a root of $x^n-y^n\in\mathbb R[x]$.

Comment: Does this come out of the Binomial series ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series

Comment: @ Surb  nice formulation!! 
@Matthias  I don't think it's related. just develop the right hand side

Comment: A homogeneous geometric power series ( with common ratio y/x )  sum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wikipedia calls it "Difference of two nth powers" both [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization) and [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_of_two_squares).

Comment: Yes, this is a better answer. +1

Answer (score 3):

It's a special case of the [sum of a geometric progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Geometric_series):
$$
a + ar + ar^2 + \ldots + ar^{m-1} = \frac{a(1-r^m)}{1-r}
$$
In this case you can plug in $a = x^{m-1}$ and $r = \frac{y}{x}$ to get
$$
x^{m-1} + x^{m-2} y + \cdots + x y^{m-2} + y^m
= \frac{x^m - y^m}{x - y}
$$
Now just multiply over $x - y$ and you have the formula you asked about.